# Function "IDENTITY" not found when inserting audited revision using Hibernate Envers (5.6.10) with Spring Boot 2.7 (H2 2.1.214, Hibernate-core 5.6.9)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, hibernate-envers

When inserting an audited revision I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: insert into audited_revision (id, timestamp) values (default, ?)
2022-07-21 15:46:09.496 TRACE 67111 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu Jul 21 15:46:09 CEST 2022]
Hibernate: call identity()
2022-07-21 15:46:09.504  WARN 67111 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90022, SQLState: 90022
2022-07-21 15:46:09.504 ERROR 67111 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Function "IDENTITY" not found; SQL statement:
call identity() [90022-214]
2022-07-21 15:46:09.518 ERROR 67111 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [call identity()]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

According to this issue on the Hibernate Jira it is supposed to be fixed in Hibernate core 5.6.5. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14985
I'm currently using Hibernate core 5.6.9 provided by Spring Boot 2.7.2 and I still get the above issue. The column is correctly created according to this piece of logging:

```
Hibernate: create table audited_revision (id bigint generated by default as identity, timestamp timestamp, primary key (id))
```

My relevant piece of application.yaml config:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    database: H2
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      format_sql: true
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            store_data_at_delete: true
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
```

Is this a bug in Hibernate or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Hibernate core 5.6.13

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15561

Comment: Yes I've created that issue but I haven't validated if the solution works. We are currently moving towards testcontainers to fix it before Spring includes this new version of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Add `MODE=LEGACY;` in the database connection:

example `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY;
```

exemple application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY;
```

Comment: This isn't really a fix, it's a workaround. I want to fix the issue. Another workaround is not upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.X and remain on 2.6.X